# Getting Column name along with data when calling stored procedure from python

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am calling PL/SQL stored procedure from python using cx_Oracle package. The PL/SQL stored procedure is returning a SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter. I am able to get the values of the REF_CURSOR, but I am not able to get the name of the column along with values.

PFB my code

```
result_set = self.__cursor__.callproc(call_procedure, parameters)    
result_set[index].fetchall()
```

fetchall() is only returning values in an array like

```
[
  "John",
  "B",
  "Doe",
  "111223333",
  "Fri, 09 May 1997 00:00:00 GMT",
  "212 Main St, Orlando, FL",
  "M",
  25000,
  "333445555"
]
```

but i want something like this

```
{
  "FirstName": "John",
  "MInit": "B",
  "LastName": "Doe",
  "SSN": "111223333",
  "DOE": "Fri, 09 May 1997 00:00:00 GMT",
  "Addr": "212 Main St, Orlando, FL",
  "Sex": "M",
  "Sal": 25000,
  "DNO": "333445555"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get all column names from `cursor.description` and use `zip()` function to construct a list of dicts:

```
# prepare cursor and execute procedure
conn = ...
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.callproc(...)

# get only column names from cursor description
column_names_list = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]

# construct a list of dict objects (<one table row>=<one dict>) 
result_dicts = [dict(zip(column_names_list, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Should be valid on `SELECT` statements as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this  - conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way** to get the column names after call a procedure is to use the `next` built-in function over the stored_results:

```
columns = next(cursor.stored_results()).column_names
```

But I think the best approach when a **JSON format** is needed is to use a **dictionary-like cursor**:

```
dict_cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
dict_cursor.callproc("proc")
results = next(dict_cursor.stored_results()).fetchall()
```

The *results* variable is a list that contains an object for each retrieved record with column names as keys `[{column_name: first_row_value, ...}, {column_name: second_row_value, ...}, ...]`